# Create highchart density with more than 2 groups

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I tried to create highchart density with more than two groups. I found a way to add them one by one manually but there must be a better way to handle groups.

Examples: I would like to create a highchart similar to ggplot chart below without adding them one by one. Is there any way to do so?

d

```
f <- data.frame(MEI = c(-2.031, -1.999, -1.945, -1.944, -1.875, 
                       -1.873, -1.846, -2.031, -1.999, -1.945, -1.944, -1.875, -1.873, 
                       -1.846, -2.031, -1.999, -1.945, -1.944, -1.875, -1.873, -1.846, 
                       -2.031, -1.999, -1.945, -1.944, -1.875, -1.873, -1.846), 
                 Count = c(10L,0L, 15L, 1L, 6L, 10L, 18L, 10L, 0L, 15L, 1L, 6L, 10L, 0L, 15L, 
                          10L, 0L, 15L, 1L, 6L, 10L, 10L, 0L, 15L, 1L, 6L, 10L, 18L), 
                 Region = c("MidWest", "MidWest", "MidWest", "MidWest", "MidWest", "MidWest", "MidWest", 
                                        "South", "South", "South", "South", "South", "South", "South", 
                                        "South", "South", "South", "NorthEast", "NorthEast", "NorthEast", 
                                        "NorthEast", "NorthEast", "NorthEast", "NorthEast", "NorthEast", 
                                        "NorthEast", "NorthEast", "NorthEast"))
df <- data.table(ddf)
df %>%ggplot() + 
  geom_density(aes(x=MEI, group=Region, fill=Region),alpha=0.5) + 
  xlab("MEI") +
  ylab("Density")

hcdensity(df[Region=="NorthEast"]$MEI,area = TRUE) %>%
  hc_add_series(density(df[Region=="MidWest"]$MEI), area = TRUE) %>%
  hc_add_series(density(df[Region=="South"]$MEI), area = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1:** `tapply` + `reduce` + `hc_add_series`

```
tapply(df$MEI, df$Region, density) %>%
  reduce(.f = hc_add_series, .init = highchart())
```

---

**Method 2:** `map` + `hc_add_series_list`

***(Reference: [RPubs - Highcharter hc_add_series_list](https://rpubs.com/jbkunst/hc_add_series_list))***

```
ds <- map(levels(df$Region), function(x){
  dt <- density(df$MEI[df$Region == x])[1:2]
  dt <- list_parse2(as.data.frame(dt))
  list(data = dt, name = x)
})

highchart() %>% 
  hc_add_series_list(ds)
```

[image]

Comment: Works great. Thanks. Any idea how I can add colors to the area under the curve like ggplot? I thought setting `area = TRUE` supposed to take care of that

Comment: try type='area'

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't figure out a way to do so directly in `highcharter`. But if you calculate the densities beforehand and use `purrr`'s `reduce()` function you can automatize the plot creation:

```
library(purrr)

# calculate a list of densities (one per region)
densities <- df %>% group_by(Region) %>% 
  do(den = density(.$MEI)) %>%
  .$den

# create the highchart with all densities
reduce(densities, hc_add_series, .init = highchart())
```

`reduce()` combines the list into a single object. To the first density in the list `highchart()` is applied and thus the necessary `highchart htmlwidget` is created. All the other densities are then added to it with `hc_add_series()`.